# RESOLVED - How can I replace start and end of line and concat line with sed

Tags: mysql, bash, sed

I want to store the result of my SQL query in a variable in order to use it in another query in the "in" clause.

When I do it with an INT list I have found the solution but in the context of a varach I have not yet found it.

Do you have an idea?

For information, for the int I use:

```
listID=$(/usr/mysql-5.5.40/bin/mysql  -u$USER -p$PASSWORD -h$HOST -P$PORT $SCHEMA -e "SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE where NAME="toto";"|sed '1d;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' )
```

In this case I can use listID for

```
NBMESSAGE=$(/usr/mysql-5.5.40/bin/mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWORD -h$HOST -P$PORT $SCHEMAMESSAGE -e "SELECT count(*) FROM MESSAGE where AUTOR_ID in ($listID)"|sed '1d')
```

then, I do

```
echo " Nombre de message $NBMESSAGE "
```

Thanks
Edit:
I had test my requete and result is good and produce this , in the Database ID are VARCHAR:

```
ID
1
12
13
14
15
16
17
```

When I pass |sed '1d;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' I obtain

1,12,13,14,15,16,17

But I want have:

'1','12','13','14','15','16','17'

When I manage to get this result I will pass it in another query which does a count. I would post it as well.

EDIT 2:

I Solve my problem with this command, I share it with you :

```sh
listID=$(/usr/mysql-5.5.40/bin/mysql  -u$USER -p$PASSWORD -h$HOST -P$PORT $SCHEMA -e "SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE where NAME="toto";"|se
d '1d;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/'"'"','"'"'/g;s/^/'"'"'/g;s/$/'"'"'/g')
```

In this cas when I do a

`echo " $listID "`

I obtain `'1','2','3','4'`

thanks

Comment: Learn to use SQL and avoid SQL parsing in bash. `SELECT AUTOR_ID, count(*) FROM MESSAGE JOIN MYTABLE ON MESSAGE.AUTOR_ID=MYTABLE.ID WHERE NAME="toto" GROUP BY AUTOR_ID`. Also look at mysql options, there's a bunch of option for batch processing that alter its output.

Comment: Thanks but it's not possible in my case because I work on 2 different database.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM DB1.MESSAGE JOIN DB2.MYTABLE....`. Select statements can be across databases on the same server.

Comment: I did not think about it. the concern is that this return sending me hundreds of lines I would really like to get a result same result described in order to avoid making tons of calls to the Database.

Comment: In order for me to help you with your sed question, can you provide example input and corresponding output.

Comment: the entry corresponds to a return of a select on a database.
So I get a variable with the name of the column in the first row, then several rows with one values per row.
Is :
```ID
lalala
tototo
tatata
```

I would like to obtain:
```  'lalala','tototo','tatata' ```
One line with all result under simple quotes for each original row.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].  Add this info: **1** sample data.  **2** Query no1 returns what?  Raw.  Before the `sed`.  And then after the `sed`. **3** Does that work ok for your requirements?  **4** what does the second query return? **6** please edit your question for more information.  Do not respond in the comments, since it is harder to read.  And some might not read all the comments, so make your question complete on its own.   **6** have you tried your queries manually?  Does that work ok?

Comment: Thanks, I  have just update my post.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have a MySQL database with your dataset, I built this simple script that prints the output you are expecting:

printoutput.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "ID"
echo "1"
echo "12"
echo "13"
echo "14"
echo "15"
echo "16"
echo "17"
```

This second script processes the output from the script above:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read the result of the command into an array
# If the command fails, \0 is returned.  The RESULTS array will have only 1 empty element
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a RESULTS < <(./printoutput.bash && printf '\0')

# Remove the first element
unset 'RESULTS[0]'

# Just to check that the unset worked
declare -p RESULTS

echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"

# This loops through the array, adding ' before and ', after each value
result=$(printf "'%s'," "${RESULTS[@]}")

# Remove the last ,
finalresult="${result%?}"

echo "$finalresult"
```

The method I use is to get rid of the `\n` all together by sending the output to an array.  The array is then printed, adding single quotes and a comma.  Then the last comma is removed.

Running the second script gives me the output you wanted:

```
./secondscript.bash 
declare -a RESULTS=([1]="1" [2]="12" [3]="13" [4]="14" [5]="15" [6]="16" [7]="17")
-----------------------------------------------------------
'1','12','13','14','15','16','17'
```

Comment: If it is resolved based on this answer, please accept it (the check mark on the left of the answer).  Much appreciated.